# CatBoost randomized_search with train/test splits

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

The CatBoost documentation says the `randomized_search` method can accept train and test splits via the `cv` parameter, instead of defining a cross validation approach. To do this, one should provide:

> An iterable yielding train and test splits as arrays of indices.

How do we define this object?

As a broken example, say my feature dataset has 10 rows.
I want to use the first 5 rows for training, and the last 5 rows for validation/testing.

I extract the index values

```
train_index = X[0:5].index
test_index = X[5:10].index
```

I supply the indexes to the `randomized_search` method

```
a_search = model.randomized_search(param_distributions=params, 
                                   X = X,
                                   y = y,
                                   n_iter=5,
                                   cv={train_index,test_index})
```

This set that I provide in `cv={train_index,test_index}` is a non-starter, as it's not iterable, but I am at a loss as to how such an iterable should look. I simply want to define which rows of `X` and `y` should be used for training, and which for testing. The goal is to speed up training by dispensing with cross validation, and using a dedicated validation dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list of tuples:

```
cv=[(train_index, test_index)]
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from catboost import CatBoost

# generate the data
data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(10, 3))
labels = np.mean(a=data, axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.hstack([data, np.expand_dims(labels, axis=1)]),
    columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'y']
)

# split the data
train_index = df.index[:5]
test_index = df.index[5:]

# instantiate the model
model = CatBoost()

# tune the model
results = model.randomized_search(
    param_distributions={
        'depth': [2, 3, 4],
        'iterations': [5, 6, 7]
    },
    X=df[['x1', 'x2', 'x3']],
    y=df['y'],
    cv=[(train_index, test_index)],
)
```